# How do I display PDF files with Drupal

Tags: drupal, pdf, drupal-modules

I am new to Drupal.

Which module do I use to display forms saved as PDF files so that they look like this:

http://www.cra-arc.gc.ca/E/pbg/tf/t3ret/t3ret-10e.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just link the pdf and let the browser plugin handle them.  The appearance of the PDF shouldn't have anything to do with what you are using to deliver it.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'd have to format the form in that fashion, however, this might be a good start for you.

http://drupal.org/project/print

Comment: +1 for the Print module, that way you don't have to manually upload a pdf version of every page (nor update the pdf when you edit the page)